# What is the best way to have long string literals in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heredoc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Multiline strings in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/multiline-strings-in-javascript)

In Ruby you can do something like this:

```
temp = <<-SQLCODE
  select * from users
SQLCODE
```

This way you have very long string literals in your code without having to escape lots of characters. Is there something similar in JavaScript?

Currently I have JavaScript code like this, and it's driving me nuts...

```
  new Element.update(lightbox_id, " \
    <div id='overlay' class='overlay' > \
    </div> \
    <div id='lightbox' class='lightbox'> \
      <div class='lightbox_title'> \
        <div class='corner_image' onclick=\"close_lightbox();return false;\"><a href='#'>" + corner_image + "</a></div> \
        <div class='lightboxname' id='lightboxname'>" + title + "</div> \
        <div class='close_image'> \
          <a href='#' onclick=\"close_lightbox();return false;\">Close</a> or Escape key\
        </div> \
      </div> \
      <div id='" + lightbox_content_id + "' class='lightbox_content'>    \
      </div> \
      <script>  \
        watch_for_escape(); \
      </script> \
    </div> \
");
```

Comment: Short answer: no, you can't have literal newlines in JS strings without the continuation character.
A few other suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/multiline-strings-in-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax you are referring to is often known as [here-document (or HEREDOC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heredoc) and no, it is not available in Javascript.

Adding a backslash as you have been doing is the appropriate way to span strings over multiple lines in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Having html inline like that is bad practice, but if you really want to handle it cleaner, try this:

Place a hidden div on your page with the html you want, and replace the custom params with something like {title}. When calling update, pass yourdiv.innerHTML.replace(...

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it makes it difficult to encapsulate functionality within a single Javascript file - for example, writing a plugin that needs to insert specific content into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails, then it becomes a lot cleaner with rjs to update a div with some multiline HTML:

```
page.replace__html 'lightbox_id', :partial => 'overlay'
```

then `overlay.html.erb` would contain the raw html above without escaping.

The added benefit is that the fragment 'overlay' could also be used in the initial page load as well, which in a lot of cases is what you want.